# Incorrect Referring URLs - What can be the cause?

Tags: html, http, http-headers, httprequest, referrer

I am running a website with affiliate links .

When the visitors of `mydomain.com/page.php` click on such an affiliate link, 
they are being sent to a link on a domain owned by the affilate network (`network.com/link`), and then redirected through the affiliate network, to the relevant page in the store (`store.com/page.asp`).

Over the last two months, the reports of the affiliate network indicate that about 13,000 clicks that I sent to such links, carried `mydomain.com/page.php` as the referring URL, as I would expect.

However, about 20 other clicks carried abnormal referring URLs, such as:

`http://app.mam.vaccint.com/getapp/CT3297962/mam.html`

`http://www.store.com/page.asp`

`http://www.network.com/link`

`http://apnwidgets.ask.com/widget/everest/radio/4/radio-button.html`

`http://search.yahoo.com/search`

`http://www.google.com/webhp`

`http://www.bing.com/`

`http://192.168.1.1/spyware/blockpage`

Unfortunately, This has led the compliance team of my affiliate network to believe that I have a hidden traffic source apart from my website, they claim that it appears to be as if I am using some kind of a third party software to send traffic to `store.com`, which is not true of course.

They are holding me accountable for this situation and I am required to provide explanations to this situation.

What could have caused my website visitors to arrive at `network.com` / `store.com` while carrying the above referring URLs?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure though, but looking at the referring URL's its quite certain that these pages had your content listed on their webpages. Like:

- e.g. google.com/webhp - listing the result content / cache / image result of your webpage
- Bing.com - another result related webpage (generally web cache)
- 192.168.1.1/spyware/blockpage - looks like someone accessed your portal but ended up reaching this firewall custom page. But somehow the affiliate widget got loaded as it would have been permitted by the firewall.
- *Store.com/page.asp* & *network.com/link* - looks like some internal redirected urls which sent traffic to the relevant page (store.com/page.asp)
- (rest other) - all other links also can have a similar story which ended up sending traffic to your affiliate network, but had another URL.

I'm sure if you replicate this case in front of them via Google cache / Bing cache, they would get a better understanding of the issue.
Else, try to identify the source referrer of page: network.com/link, which probably is under their control and they would have access to the logs.